# Rotation error (Blender To Unity)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, blender

I made a simple cubic guy and armature for this guy in blender. Then I made some animations which are walk and 3 aim animation to use in blend tree. In blender everything looks good but when I import this animations to Unity, I realise that rotation of the arms are different. Let me show my problem with some ss. This is how the model looks in blender. [image: Blender]

and when I import this model to Unity it looks like this :
[image]

I believe you guys can see the rotation difference between the upper arms. I couldnt find what is wrong. Anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem could be an animation keyframe setting in Blender.  I would scroll through the Blender timeline on that animation and see if anything appears wrong.

Also, this Unity script could help with rotation conversion between the different coordinate systems between Blender and Unity (just in case this might be the problem): http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/FixBlenderImportRotation

Comment: Everything fine in blender. I will check the other thing you have mentioned

Comment: Well I tought this fixed my problem but actually its something different I believe. When I import the model actually it looks good. (I mean exact same with belender) I realised that this rotation error occurs right after I choose a rig. But still couldnt fix it.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the rigging configuration.  Maybe there's an IK limit setting on the shoulder bones causing the rotations to limit or maybe there's a hidden rotation key or some other unknown key setting causing the issue.

Comment: I tried to use different fbx files for ever animation and character. I mean the first fbx file has no animation and I created an avatar for it. Then I used this avatar for other animation files. Also I realised that this error happens right after I choose a rig for the imported file. Before that still everything looks fine. Its is so annoying :( Ah also I didnt use any IK bone or limit for any bone. I may upload the blend files if you want to check.

Comment: Sure, post it somewhere and give the URL I'll take a look.